# Likelihood Factorization

Tags: maximum-likelihood, covariance, likelihood, gaussian-process

Optimizing the full likelihood function is sometimes time consuming and contains a lot of numerical issues and instabilities especially when matrix inversion is needed.
If we have 3 input vectors $\boldsymbol{y}_{1},\boldsymbol{y}_{2},\boldsymbol{y}_{3}$ let $\mathbf{y}=[\boldsymbol{y}_{1},\boldsymbol{y}_{2},\boldsymbol{y}_{3}]$. Based on this, I want to model $\mathbf{y}$
$$ \mathbf{y}\sim N(0,K)$$ where K is a joint covariance matrix between all three input vectors.
The Inputs are connected as shown in the figure below: $\boldsymbol{y}_{1}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}_{2}$ are independent while both $\boldsymbol{y}_{1}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}_{2}$ depend on $\boldsymbol{y}_{3}$.
In other words the covariance matrix $K$ is expressed as follows
$$K=\begin{pmatrix}
k_{11} & 0 & k_{13}\\ 
0& k_{22} & k_{23} \\ 
k_{13} &  k_{23} & k_{33}
\end{pmatrix}$$
Where $k$ is any postive semidefinite covariance function. 
Is there any specific way for me to exploit this independence and factorize the full likelihood function for example can I write $$f(\boldsymbol{y}_{1},\boldsymbol{y}_{2},\boldsymbol{y}_{3})=f(\boldsymbol{y}_{3}|\boldsymbol{y}_{1},\boldsymbol{y}_{2})*f(\boldsymbol{y}_{1})*f(\boldsymbol{y}_{2})$$ and optimize each part seprately? and what is the expression of $f(\boldsymbol{y}_{3}|\boldsymbol{y}_{1},\boldsymbol{y}_{2})$ given the covariance matrix above. Also is there a specific way I can use a composite likelihood approach such as a pairwise likelihood method.

Any good references on such normal likelihood factorizations is greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to optimize each part separately since  all three of the factored likelihood functions share parameters.

Comment: @AlexR. Yes this is true , for this reason I am searching for a possible different method to factorize my likelihood and thus simplify the optimization problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether this winds up being a good thing to do, but you can express the distribution of $y_3$  conditional on $y_1,y_2$, which is a 1D Normal, using the standard Schur complement approach shown in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions .

Let $\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3$ be the means of $y_1,y_2,y_3$.

Denote $K_{12}$ as the diagonal matrix with entries $k_{11}$ and $k_{22}$, i.e., the covariance matrix of $[y_1,y_2]^T$. Its inverse is obtained by inverting the diagonal elements.

$y_3$ conditional on $[y_1,y_2]^{T} = [x_1,x_2]^{T}$ is Normal and has
$$mean = \mu_3 + [k_{13},k_{23}] K_{12}^{-1} [x_1 - \mu1,x_2 - \mu_2]^{T}$$
and $$variance = k_{33} - [k_{13},k_{23}] K_{12}^{-1} [k_{13},k_{23}]^T$$

Comment: You can use this to form a factorized likelihood for your scenario.

Comment: Based on your derivation, I cannot optimize each part of my likelihood separately since the three factors share parameters. Is there a well known approximation for such cases ?

Comment: Not that I know of. But I don't know everything. If you want to get a feel for what's going on with multivariate normal likelihood and constraints, look at exercise 7.4 on pp. 303-304 of http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf .