# Composite Likelihood in the multivariate gaussian distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, likelihood

Given a multivariate gaussian distribution of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
y_{1}\\y_{2} \\y_{3}\end{pmatrix} \sim N\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0 
\\0
\end{pmatrix}, &\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_{1}^{2} & 0 & \rho\sigma_{1}\sigma_{3}\\ 
0& \sigma_{2}^{2} & \rho\sigma_{2}\sigma_{3}\\ 
\rho\sigma_{1}\sigma_{3} &  \rho\sigma_{2}\sigma_{3} & \sigma_{3}^{2}
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{pmatrix}$$
Since it is known in the gaussian distribution that zero covariance implies independence then is it safe to write the likelihood as:
$$f(y_{1},y_{2},y_{3})=f(y_{3}|y_{1},y_{2})*f(y_{1})*f(y_{2})$$

If yes, then how can we write  $f(y_{1},y_{2},y_{3})$

PS : A similar question has been asked in cross validated : [Likelihood Factorization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231141/likelihood-factorization)

Comment: This seems to be just a rewrite of your previous question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231141/likelihood-factorization . Either that question should have been edited, or at minimum, a link provided to it.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I am adding a link now

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=conditional+normal+multivariate for many more answers.